# Update grandchild repeater field with value per row

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to take the following data from a table:

[image]

And input it to a nested [ACF repeater field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_sub_row/). I've got very close in that it's creating the correct amount of tables (3 from the example), the correct amount of columns for each table.

The last part isn't quite working, it's only inputting the last row of data into the "Information" repeater, which suggests it's not iterating the row numbers, therefore just inputting it to row 1.

**Where am I going wrong (see code at the bottom)? So for the first table, each information table should have 4 rows of data in it for each column.**

[image]

- Top repeater (product codes): field_5ae0882f9d6f9

  - Nested repeater 1 (table): field_5b3f409de191a

    - Nested repeater 2 (information): field_5ae088999d6fb

      - Field to update (text): field_5ae088b79d6fc

Here's the code:

```
     $value = array();
      $rowcount = 1;
      while($row = next($rows)){

          $cells = $row->find('td');
          $columnsCount = count($cells);
          $counter = 1;
          foreach ($cells as $cell) {
            $value = array(
              "field_5ae088999d6fb" => array(
                array("field_5ae088b79d6fc" => strip_tags($cell->innertext))
              )
            );
            update_sub_row( array('field_5ae0882f9d6f9', $tablecounter, 'field_5b3f409de191a'), $counter, $value, $post_id );
            $value = array();
            $counter++;
          }

        $rowcount++;

  }

  $tablecounter++;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to *my* fields structure below:

```
Field Name        Field Key           Type
product_codes     field_5b4d8f7246886 Repeater
  - table         field_5b4d8fd946888 Repeater
    - information field_5b4d906246889 Repeater
      - text      field_5b4d907f4688a Text
```

Here's how you can update the *first* `information` row in the *first* `table`:

Using [`update_sub_row()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_sub_row/):

```
// Here, we build the ancestors, starting from the TOPMOST LEVEL down to the
// field that we're updating its value.
$selector = [
    'field_5b4d8f7246886', 1, // selects the first `table` in `product_codes`
    'field_5b4d8fd946888',    // selects ALL the `information` rows
];

update_sub_row( $selector, 1, [
    'field_5b4d906246889' => [
        [ 'field_5b4d907f4688a' => '040-811' ],
        [ 'field_5b4d907f4688a' => '040-821' ],
        [ 'field_5b4d907f4688a' => 'Standard Size Fibre Optic Handle' ],
        [ 'field_5b4d907f4688a' => '1' ],
    ],
] );
```

Using [`update_sub_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_sub_field/):

```
// Here, we build the ancestors, starting from the TOPMOST LEVEL down to the
// field that we're updating its value.
$selector = [
    'field_5b4d8f7246886', 1, // selects the first `table` in `product_codes`
    'field_5b4d8fd946888', 1, // selects the first `information` row
    'field_5b4d906246889',    // finally, selects all `text` columns
];

update_sub_field( $selector, [
    [ 'field_5b4d907f4688a' => '040-811' ],
    [ 'field_5b4d907f4688a' => '040-821' ],
    [ 'field_5b4d907f4688a' => 'Standard Size Fibre Optic Handle' ],
    [ 'field_5b4d907f4688a' => '1' ],
] );
```

I hope that helps you, and do let me know if you need further assistance.

---

### UPDATE

Try this code:

```
$the_row = [
    'field_5ae0882f9d6f9', $tablecounter,
    'field_5b3f409de191a',
];

//$value = array();
$rowcount = 1;
foreach ( $rows as $row ) {

    $cells = $row->find('td');
    //$columnsCount = count($cells);
    //$counter = 1;
    $cols = [];
    foreach ($cells as $cell) {
        $value = strip_tags($cell->innertext);
        $cols[] = [ 'field_5ae088b79d6fc' => $value ];
        //$counter++;
    }

    update_sub_row( $the_row, $rowcount, [
        'field_5ae088999d6fb' => $cols,
    ], $post_id );

    $rowcount++;

}

$tablecounter++;
```

Comment: Just so I can test it properly, where in my loop does that go and what is it replacing? Thanks

Comment: Ok, let me write an example based on your loop.

Comment: Thanks very much. Just to mention that my field data is dynamic so I can't hard code any text.

Comment: Sure. The ones I used in the current answer, they're just examples so you can see how to generate the ancestors as in `update_sub_row( $ancestors, $i, $row, $post_id );`.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. (or the example loop)

Comment: Do check the code again, I've made a few edits after my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you so much, I added a tiny amendment but it works. I'm just going to double check but on the surface it looks like it's worked. Thanks so much, been on this for days!!

Comment: One smallish amendment, it's skipping the first line in each table - I'd originally put that in to not add the column titles (in the first table - Knurled & satin). How can I ignore that and just take all rows? It's this line but not sure on the syntax `while ( $row = next($rows) ) {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176166/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-rob).